# Circular Reference Error when trying to get column names from linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc 4 to get the column names of a linq to sql model using the following code in my controller:

```
var dataContext = new OrdersDataContext();
var columnNames = dataContext.Mapping.MappingSource
                    .GetModel(typeof(OrdersDataContext))
                    .GetMetaType(typeof(Order))
                    .DataMembers;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
'System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedRootType
```

Where might this error be coming from.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory. You are attempting to serialize an object graph containing circular references.

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091198/circular-reference-linq-to-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check your relationships between the tables in the DBML file. You probably have a cycle (circle) between them. Follow the lines.